# Android get data if data is one hour old from the Web Services

Tags: android

I have the android application where the webservices data is not frequently updated say once in a day.

I have to save data in DB for offline viewing as well, right now I am thinking that, when user clicks an button to get data it checks if the last data entered in DB is one hour old, if no then no downloading from web service if yes then download.

So, at the time I am saving data I will save current time with it , and calculate the difference and get latest data.

Is this a correct approach.

Asmi

Answer (score 1):

Having a field in database table just for this purpose isn't an ideal approach. Instead, you should save the current time in SharedPreferences and compare the time to see if data needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Okay, will try the SharedPreferences for this. This may be different question but I want that my saving into database should not be limited to activity. That means, I get data and display it first and the save into DB in separate function(as it takes time).It is working fine, but If user clicks another activity then saving Data into DB is stopped in middle..any ideas for this